# FLUTTER: Divider() in Column inside a Row does not appear

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to put a divider in a Column inside a Row but the divider does not appear. I saw some questions about the Row should not be used but in my case, I need the Row. Here is the simplest code, I need the divider to be shown

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: const [
                Text('up'),
                Divider(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  thickness: 2,
                ),
                Text('bottom'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the divider to show, you need to warp your `Divider()` with a `SizedBox()` and define a set width. As well as removing `const` form the `Column()` since we're using `MediaQuery`:

```dart
 SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Divider(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    thickness: 2,
                  ),
                ),
```

Result:

[image]

---

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({required this.title});
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Text('up'),
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Divider(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    thickness: 2,
                  ),
                ),
                Text('bottom'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the structure is

```
Center
 - Row
   - Column
     - Text
     - Divider
     - Text
```

This divider doesn't get any constrained and the result is invisible on UI.

Wrapping  `Divider` with `SizedBox` provide the constraints, and we are able to see the divider. Also you can go for `Expanded` on `Column` widget.

```dart
body: Center(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: const [
            Text('up'),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.green,
              thickness: 2,
            ),
            Text('bottom'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```